# Как сделать сопоставление двух csv файлов на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть 2 csv файла.
В первом хранятся параметры товара, во втором хранится id и src для картинки.

Первый файл:

```
'id_product','reference','id_category_default','price','description_short',' description','name_product'
```

Второй файл:

```
'id_product','src'
```

В результате должно идти сопоставление по id_product и добавление src

Пробовал делать так, но не получается вывести все параметры.

```
from csv import reader

d = dict(reader(open('Первый.csv')))

for id, src in (reader(open('Второй.csv'))):

    if id in d:
        print(id, d[id], src)
```

вот пример из первого файла:

```
'id_product','reference','id_category_default','price','description_short',' description','name_product' 
3,00100,22,0,,,"Фляжка (береста, металл)" 
5,00100-10,22,0,,,Магнит (береста) 
6,00100-11,22,0,,,"Шкатулка (береста, дерево)"
```

вот второй файл:

```
'id_product','src' 
3,"souvenires.ru/18462/flyazhka-beresta-metall.jpg" 
4,"souvenires.ru/18469/shkatulka-derevo-lazernaya-gravirovka .jpg" 
5,"souvenires.ru/18478/magnit-beresta.jpg"  
7,"souvenires.ru/18472/shkatluka-pod-format-a4-beresta-derev o.jpg" 
8,"souvenires.ru/18489/shkatulka-pod-butylku-beresta-derevo. jpg"
```

Результат хотелось бы получить так:

```
'id_product','reference','id_category_default','price','description_short',' description','name_product', 'src'
3,00100,22,0,,,"Фляжка (береста, металл)","souvenires.ru/18462/flyazhka-beresta-metall.jpg"
```

Comment: А можно в вопрос добавить пример данных из первого файла и второго, и что должно в итоге показать скрипт? Нужно ведь перебрать из первого файла id_product и вывести id_product и src из второго файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение:

```
import csv


with open('result.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as all_file:
    writer = csv.writer(all_file)

    id_by_url = dict(csv.reader(open('2.csv', encoding='utf-8')))

    # Вытаскиваем первый элемент, а все остальные помещаем в список items
    for id_product, *items in csv.reader(open('1.csv', encoding='utf-8')):
        # Если нет id
        if id_product not in id_by_url:
            continue

        url = id_by_url[id_product]
        
        # Составляем строку как список
        row = [id_product] + items + [url]

        print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот и решение сопоставления csv файлов с объединением по одинаковым параметрам.

```
import csv
from csv import reader

with open('all.csv', 'w') as all_file:
    writer = csv.writer(all_file)

d = dict(reader(open('broken_url.csv')))
for id_product,reference,id_category_default,price,description_short,description,name_product in (reader(open('new_product.csv'))):
    if id_product in d:
        # print(id_product, reference,id_category_default,price,description_short,description,name_product, d[id_product])
        writer.writerow([id_product,reference,id_category_default,price,description_short,description,name_product, d[id_product]])
```

Comment: Код ведь не рабочий, т.к. файл закрыт, поэтому в writer.writerow будет ошибка